# Breaking out of a .on('click')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a radio button that has a dropdown box:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="pan" class="radioButton" value="pan">
  <label for="pan">PAN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="singleColor" class="radioButton" value="singleColor">
  <label for="singleColor"> 
       <span>
           <select name="imageColor" id="selectedColor">
               <option value="red" selected="selected">Red</option>
               <option value="red">Green</option>
               <option value="red">Blue</option>
           </select>
       </span>
    </label>
</form>
```

If I click the dropdown box without selecting the radio button - nothing happens, which is expected.
If I click the radio button, it passes the current value and if I change the value with the radio clicked it updates the value.
Everything works fine in that sense, however, if I click the other radio button in "pan" and then select a color from the drop down, that color still gets passed and the image for that color comes in.
I don't want the color to be read from the dropdown unless that radio button is selected.  Anyone know a way to break out of the .on('click') from another function?

Here's an example of the javascript:

```
$('#singleColor).on('click',function() {
    if($('selectedColor').val() === "red") {
       //ajax code for red
    }
    if($('selectedColor').val() === "green") {
       //ajax code for green
    }
    $('#selectedColor').change(function () {
        if($('#selectedColor').val() === "red") { 
            //ajax code for red
        }
        if($('#selectedColor').val() === "green") { 
            //ajax code for green
        }
    }
}
```

So essentially - when the radio button is not selected for this - but I use the dropdown it still has access to that an you can bring in the image.
It only gains access when you click the radio button, so initially, if you were to refresh the page and click the dropdown you wouldn't get a response...
but when you click the radio button for the dropdown and then click another radio button then access the dropdown you will always get a response.

Sorry if this is a bit wordy..was having a hard time trying to explain the problem.

If you need any more information please let me know.  Thank  you!

Comment: Get yourself into the habit of setting a variable to the value you get from a function, like `$('#selectedColor').val()` (which is actually two functions), if you use that value more than once. Later developers will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click `#singleColor` radio, you attach a `change` event listener to the other element and it stays on it. Then it doesn't matter if your radio button is clicked or not, cause the other event listener is executed on dropdown element value change.

The proper solution would be to attach only once `change` event listener to dropdown list and then check if #singleColor radio is checked (or not).

```js
$('#selectedColor').change(function () {
    if (! $('#singleColor').is(':checked'))
        return; // dont do anything if radio not checked

    if ($(this).val() === "red") { 
        // ajax code for red
    }

    if ($(this).val() === "green") { 
        // ajax code for green
    }
}
```

Also if you want to trigger this event and ajax functions on 'radio' checking, you need to simply use `trigger` function on dropdown element in radio `click` event:

```js
$('#singleColor').on('click' function () {
    $('selectedColor').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Gosh I have been trying everything with this and that makes complete sense now that you mentioned it.  Thank you for helping!

Comment: You're welcome :) 
I've edited my answer and added one thing if you want to execute all of this on radio click.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i get your problem. It is that you want the color value to change only when the radio is selected and if it is not selected the color value should not change even if the PAN radio is selected.

You can try the below snippet

```
$('#selectedColor').on('change', function(){
    if($('#singleColor').is(':checked')){
        if($('#selectedColor').val() === "red") { 
            //ajax code for red
        }
        if($('#selectedColor').val() === "green") { 
            //ajax code for green
        }
    }
})
$('#singleColor').on('click', function(){
    if($('#selectedColor').val() === "red") { 
        //ajax code for red
    }
    if($('#selectedColor').val() === "green") { 
        //ajax code for green
    }
})
```